# installation on old network pc

Tags: networking

I have an old laptop that was originally part of a company network, possibly still is, technically. It runs on windows 7 enterprise and is complaining that the windows version is no longer valid. I would like to erase everything that is on it, install ubuntu, and give it to my grand children to service a microscope. I have the ubuntu installation files on a usb drive (or think I have, having followed a tutorial). But I have not been able to either boot from the drive or install from it. Any ideas? 
PS, I am an experienced pc user, but basically I have no idea what is going on under the hood.

Arne

Comment: You should enter the laptop's BIOS and set the boot device order such that USB has a higher priority than the hard drive. How to do that varies from for each BIOS version, but you should be able to figure it out once you enter the BIOS.

Comment: If you would like help getting a *specific pc* to boot from USB, it will improve your odds if you [edit] your question and *tell us what kind of pc it is*.

Comment: Thanks very much for your assistance. Everything seems to be solved by now. Apparently, the underlying problem was the usb stick I was using, which itself was protected by a pw, thus not making itself known to the BIOS. So I switched that, and since then life has been easy. Thank You!